# Google Cloud AppEngine - NPM Dependency - Invalid authentication credentials

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, npm, google-cloud-platform, dependencies

I've created a Node.js project (let's call it AA) in GC (Google cloud) Repository and then created another project (BB) and used `AA` as a dependency:

```
"dependencies": {
  "@slack/client": "^4.9.0",
  "axios": "^0.18.0",
  "big-integer": "^1.6.41",
  "https-proxy-agent": "^2.2.1",
  "moment": "^2.24.0",
  "mongoose-auto-increment": "^5.0.1",
  "mssql": "^4.3.0",
  "xml2js": "^0.4.19",
  "AA": "git+https://source.developers.google.com/p/AA/r/AA",
}
```

now when I try to deploy it to AppEngine:

```
gcloud -q app deploy server/app-prod.yaml --project BB
```

i'm getting `Invalid authentication credentials.` error:

```
Step #1: npm ERR! Error while executing:
Step #1: npm ERR! /usr/bin/git ls-remote -h -t https://source.developers.google.com/p/AA/r/AA
Step #1: npm ERR!
Step #1: npm ERR! fatal: remote error:
Step #1: npm ERR!
Step #1: npm ERR!
Step #1: npm ERR! Invalid authentication credentials.
Step #1: npm ERR!
Step #1: npm ERR! Please generate a new identifier:
Step #1: npm ERR!   https://source.developers.google.com/new-password
Step #1: npm ERR!
Step #1: npm ERR!
Step #1: npm ERR!
Step #1: npm ERR! exited with error code: 128
Step #1:
Step #1: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
Step #1: npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2019-03-31T12_25_41_034Z-debug.log
Step #1: error building image: error building stage: waiting for process to exit: exit status 1
```

it seems the service running the build on the AppEngine doesn't have permissions of the AA repository. however, I have no idea which user is it or what permissions do I need to give him. I couldn't find any answers on it in google cloud pages and I don't have support package.

I hope someone other then I did it before and can help me.
I have `AA` and `BB` since the code used in `AA` will be used in other projects as well (this is a utility project)

Comment: Hope you have run ```gcloud init``` to complete authentication and followed steps.

Comment: Are you able to authenticate a [gcloud command](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/source/repos/clone) to clone the source code? For example `gcloud source repos clone REPOSITORY_NAME`

Comment: @YogenderSingh I have `gcloud init` and I am able to also install the dependencies locally, so I have authentication locally

Comment: @ChristopherP yes, I have cloned the repo locally

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can work around this problem by using a custom runtime and executing the git user initialisation script in your Dockerfile.

1. Add the dependency to your package.json the same way you did in your question

   ```
   "AA": "git+https://source.developers.google.com/p/AA/r/AA"
   ```
2. Obtain the initialisation script by going to [this URL](https://source.developers.google.com/auth/start?scopes=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform&state=) and following the authentication steps.
3. Store it in a file in your project's root directory.
   Change the runtime in your app.yaml to 'custom'. Add a Dockerfile like the following:

   ```
   FROM gcr.io/google_appengine/nodejs

   RUN /usr/local/bin/install_node '>=8.0.0'
   COPY . /app/

   #Change to filename of the script stored in step 1 
   RUN /bin/bash /app/auth.bash 

   RUN npm install --unsafe-perm || \
     ((if [ -f npm-debug.log ]; then \
         cat npm-debug.log; \
       fi) && false)
   CMD npm start
   ```
4. Run `gcloud app deploy`

Comment: ok, I'll try it, but this seems like an awful lot of workaround... is that the what Google team had in mind?

Comment: In any scenario where the runtime is missing something that's necessary to your application or build (credentials, in this case), then the solution would be to implement it in a custom runtime.

Comment: sorry but this doesn't work. i've been working all day on it and no progress. no matter how i try to create, copy, or just send the auth.bash file, it still return the error message. on top of that, i am getting errors when trying to echo the content of files i'm creating (for example when using the `touch` command)

Comment: sounds like you're having some trouble with the dockerfile. Can you let me know exactly what sort of error you're getting?

Comment: the problem was that in copy-paste you get added Carriage Return (`\r`) to the end of a line, which cause the auth.sh to fail (don't know why). once removed it works.
i don't know how, but you should add this to the answer so other will know. also, you can add that this is an official solution from google could team as they suggested the same